# TypeScript: Declaring class's functions in multiply files

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to split class declaration over files?
e.g properties, constructor and some functions in one file and other functions in other file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like MartyIX wrote, it isn't directly supported.

However, there's a way to do it though. The methods need to be defined as properties, but doing so can cause inheritance issues.

File 1:

```
class Foo {
    bar() {}
    hello: (world: string) => any;
}
```

File 2:

```
Foo.prototype.hello = function (world: string) {
    console.log('hello ' + world);
};

// Works
new Foo().hello('world');

class Bar extends Foo {}

// Works
new Bar().hello('world');

class Bam extends Foo {}
    // Error TS2425
    hello () {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The feature is called `partial classes` and it isn't supported as of now.

You can add your +1 to this bug issue https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/563 :)